# Recursive base representation

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, radix

I'm having the joy of learning recursion over again in Python, while the basics come easily, there seems to be a point where I just lose the ability to problem solve recursively.

For example problems like the one below.

*Write a recursive function base that has two parameters, n, a base 10 positive integer, and b, an integer between 2 and 9.   The function returns the base b representation of the number n.  The base b representation of a number uses the digits 0,..,b-1 and the place of the digits indicate powers of the base.*

```
>>> base(5,3)  # write 5 in base 3
'12'

>>> base(887,7)  # write 887 in base 7
'2405'
```

I have the problem done without using recursion.

```
def base(n, b):
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    digits = []
    while n:
        digits.append(int(n % b))
        n //= b
    return digits[::-1]
```

If someone would be willing to walk me through solving this problem recursively it would be greatly appreciated.

Also, is the best way to learn to think recursively to practice problem after problem after problem? I'm used to having new concepts instantly click for me, that fact that I've hit this brick wall with recursion is somewhat worrying to me.

Comment: "while this does return the correct answer, it's done inefficiently" - what makes you think your iterative solution is inefficient? There don't seem to be any obvious deficiencies. Strictly speaking, there are algorithms with better asymptotic runtime, but they require way more sophisticated background knowledge than you could reasonably be expected to possess, and they only become worthwhile once the numbers involved are several hundred digits long.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that recursive functions usually have got bad performances because of their big overhead

Comment: Wait, Python 3? You should be using `//=` instead of `/=` for floor division. Maybe that's why you think it's inefficient; if you're using true division, you're getting the results wrong.

Comment: @user2357112 Ahhhh. Thanks! That fixed the issues with all the zeros returning before the answer (that's why I was considering it inefficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fundamental parts to a recursive program:

1. You must **know when to stop!**
2. You must be able to express the problem in terms of a solution to a smaller version of the same problem.

Let's look at your "problem":

> You want to produce a string that represents `n` written in base `b`.

Some quick rules of thumb: if the problem involves an "integer", the likely stopping point is zero. If it involves a "string" the likely stopping point is an empty string. If it involves a complex data structure like a list, the likely stopping point is an empty data structure. (This is not always true. But it's always true for classroom work. ;-)

Anyway, you have already struck on the idea of using `n` as your most significant variable, and testing it for zero.

I'm going to suggest that *that* is wrong. (Just because...)

Let's try with a slightly different termination condition: `n < b`. In that case, you know you can produce a single digit.

So:

```
if n < b:
    return str(n)
```

With that done, what can we do? Well, the rest of your code is pretty much spot on:

```
def base(n, b):
    if n < b: return str(n)
    return base(n // b, b) + str(n % b)
```

Comment: Very helpful, I hadn't noticed the issue with the termination condition before.  I will ask you the same question as I did to the previous answer to my question. How do you decide when to solve a problem recursively over iteratively? It seems recursive problem solving is much shorter and straight to the point, but from what I'm understanding, it's not always the most efficient way.

Comment: Recursion in most languages is limited by stack depth. If you have a language that optimizes "tail recursion" you can do what you like. But most languages don't, and so I tend to avoid recursion if I can "see the end." For example, problems like this one have an obvious conversion to a loop. But things like traversing a tree don't have such an obvious conversion (without implementing my own stack, etc.). So I recurse when the termination condition is not immediately obvious, and loop when I can see how to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly modified your (already pretty-good) solution.   The idea with recursion is to break the solution down into smaller subproblems.

In this case, we first want to get the digit for the ones place, which is easy: just `n%b`.  After that we need to figure out how to convert the rest of the number into base b.  That's the part we do recursively, until the rest of the number is 0, at which point we're done.

```
   def base_recur(n,b):
        if n == 0:
            return []
        return  base_recur(n//b, b) + [n%b]
```

## Outputs

```
   base_recur(887,7)
   [2, 4, 0, 5]

   base(5,3)
   [1, 2]
```

And if you want a string representation, you can wrap the result with `join`

```
"".join(str(dig) for dig in base_recur(887,7))
'2405'
```

Or you can just define the recursive function to natively return a string

```
   def base_recur(n,b):
        if n == 0:
            return ''
        return  base_recur(n//b, b) + str(n%b)
```

Comment: What's the best way to get the string representation inside of the function without a `TypeError` ?

Answer (score 1):

when doing recursion, the more efficient form is by using [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) that is doing bit of calculation in each step and carry a accumulator and in the final step you have the answer in the accumulator, and as such you don't need extra work in the way back from the recursive call, and if you can do it this way is easy to change it into a loop and viceversa, that is what you have to do in Haskell for example, if you need a loop-like calculation you do it in the form of tail recursion.

Now this problem may be solved like this

```
BASE='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' #until base 36, because why not :)

def base(n,b,acc=None):
    if acc is None:  # I need a accumulator, if I don't get one I provide one
        acc=[]
    if n < b:
        acc.append(BASE[n])
        return "".join(reversed(acc))
    else:
        n,d = divmod(n,b)      # n//b and n%b at once 
        acc.append(BASE[d])  
        return base(n,b,acc)
```

(I use a list as accumulator because in python string are inmutables, so any operation that change them make a copy of it, so to spare me of that I use a list)

test

```
>>> base(0,16)
'0'
>>> base(42,16)
'2A'
>>> base(5,3)
'12'
>>> base(420,25)
'GK'
>>> base(25,25)
'10'
>>> base(42,2)
'101010'
```